# jquery scroll to webpage part

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scrolltop

I have a problem with jquery which makes my webpage jump to certain part on load/refresh and I want to remove that but I can't and don't know how since that is the part of the code of some contact form I downloaded and want to remove this part.
I am familiar only with html and css when we talk about web development so all I could figure out is that **scrollTop** makes my webpage do that. I found that part in jquery code and it solves my problem but then I lose my contact form functions.

Here is the code and if you can explain it to me or just fix that part which bothers me I would really appreciate it and would help me alot.

```
jQuery.fn.visible=function(){return this.each(function(){var a=$(this)[0].offsetTop;var c=$(this).height();var b=$(this).parent();$(b).animate({scrollTop:a+c/2-$(b).height()/2},0)})};
```

Sorry for arrangement but since I don't know anything about this I don't know how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the animation - `$(b).animate({scrollTop:a+c/2-$(b).height()/2},0)})`

very possible you don't need this stuff either `var c=$(this).height();var b=$(this).parent();$(b).animate({scrollTop:a+c/2-$(b).height()/2},0)})`

Do you have a webpage we can see this on?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Nathaniel Kam but removing that part of code do all the same like removing any part of that code. Disables the page scrolling on load but also disables some parts of my contact form functions. Maybe I should provide you with other parts of that code or you could see what is the problem when I get my webpage up and running. For now it's offline but I will make it online in about 20 hours. Please stay tuned

Comment: $(b).animate({scrollTop:a+c/2-$(b).height()/2},0)}) really should have nothing to do with the form other than the animation (ie no functional changes, if it does would need to see exactly what it is doing on your site.

Comment: thank you for your effort @Nathaniel Kam but I solved this problem by making simpler contact form that suits me more and does not use that js files that are being problematic